# Rails Project Connection error with MySQL DB - Access Denied for root user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I get this error when running rails with mysql db. Basically it is not giving the root user access. I have no idea why this is and have been stuck with this for a while now.

```
Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)):
Rendered /Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack- 3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered /Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (5.7ms)
Rendered /Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (17.7ms)
```

My Database.yml file is posted below for your reference. Im not sure how i check the password that MYSQL is automatically assigned to? Would it be my computer login password? Anyhow how do i check it. Also i cant simply type mysql on my command line i have to enter the entire path to access it. How do i change it. Most importantly i want to know how this access denied issue can be resolved. Thank you. Using mysql 5.5 on mac. x86_64 build.

```
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: project1_db
  pool: 5
  user : root
  username: root
  password: password
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: project1_db
  pool: 5
  user : root
  username: root
  password: password
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: project1_db
  pool: 5
  user : root
  username: root
  password: password
  host: localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql uses the one that you've set on install. Sometimes it's empty.
Try mysql -u root. If it works - remove pass string form database yaml.
If it's not empty - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+reset+password

Comment: I think my problem was that there was no password set for my root. Then i set it to the one on my yaml file and now its working fine.